# How to extract form_key parameter from the first response and pass it with the next request on magento checkout ? using jmeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter

I am a beginner in testing and QA world. I am using JMETER (.jmx script) to perform automated functional testing on magento 1.9.

So far, everything is working good for me, but having issues on checkout requests with 403 Forbidden. I have googled and found that form_key is creating issue. Because form_key is being generated dynamically.

I want to know, how to extract **form_key** parameter from the first response and pass it with the next request on magento checkout ?

So far, I have tried using CSS/Jquery Extractor to extract **form_key** but I don't know how to use this in next request. It would be really helpful if anyone can suggest good solutions to solve 403 Forbidden issue on magento checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [CSS/JQuery Extractor documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)

> **Reference Name**
>
> The name of the [JMeter variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in which to store the result.

So if you configure CSS/JQuery Extractor like:

[image: CSS JQuery JMeter Magento]

You will be able to refer the extracted value as `${FORM_KEY}` where required, i.e.

[image: Magento Post Request]

References:

- [Magento CSRF attack: A Simple Explanation](http://www.aschroder.com/2009/03/magento-csrf-attack-explanation/)
- [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites)